# Gradle: .aar library not included into compiler's output

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle project, composed of two subprojects: UI and backend library.
The library on it's own relies upon another .aar library.

Extract from library's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name: 'ActionBarSherlock', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Extract from UI's build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":my_library")
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) // all jars
}
```

When I try to build the project, build fails with following error:

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':UI:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find :ActionBarSherlock:.
     Required by:
         Project:UI:unspecified > Project:my_library:unspecified
```

I checked the .aar output for `my_library` and it does not contain `ActionBarSherlock.arr` in `libs` folder. How do I tell Gradle to include .arr files into library output?

Answer (score 0):

```
transitive = true
```

seems to be missing. For example (in the build.gradle UI):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ('com.your.company.backendlib') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```